# How to count only new user reactions based on multiple months, in different pages from a CSV with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file, which I have read with Pandas. I need to count how many new users liked each page in, multiple months.  Each user should be counted only once, if a user liked a page, that user should not be counted in the next months.

```
username,page,date
usera,sample1,2021-05-30
userb,sample1,2021-05-20
usera,sample1,2021-05-12
usera,sample1,2021-07-24
userx,sample1,2021-07-25

usera,sample2,2021-05-06
usera,sample2,2021-05-07
usera,sample2,2021-05-08
usera,sample2,2021-05-09
usera,sample2,2021-05-09
usera,sample2,2021-06-09
userx,sample2,2021-06-01
usera,sample2,2021-07-10
userx,sample2,2021-07-11
userz,sample2,2021-07-12


Expected output without //
sample1 2 new users liked in 05 month
sample1 0 new users liked in 06 month // 0 becuause usera already liked this page
sample1 1 new users liked in 07 month // 1 becuause of usera already liked this page in 05.th and 06. month 
sample2 1 users liked in 05 month  
sample2 1 users liked in 06 month   // 1 becuause of usera already liked this page2
sample2 1 users liked in 07 month   // 1 becuause of usera already liked this page2 in 05 month and userx already liked this page2 06. month
```

Here is my script counts different users in each month, but this counts the users that liked previous months

```
import pandas as pd 

username = ['usera', 'userb', 'usera', 'userd', 'userc', 'userc', 'userc', 'userf', 'userx']
page = ['sample1','sample1','sample1','sample2','sample2','sample2','sample2','sample2','sample2']
date = ['2021-05-04','2021-05-04','2021-05-05','2021-05-06','2021-05-07','2021-05-08','2021-05-09','2021-05-09','2021-06-01']

df = pd.DataFrame({'username': username, 'page': page, 'date': date})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.set_index('date').groupby('page').resample('M')['username'].nunique()
```

Here is an explanation of different way:

```
import pandas as pd

username = ['usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera', 'usera']
page = ['sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1','sample1']
date = ['2021-05-04','2021-05-04','2021-06-05','2021-05-06','2021-05-07','2021-05-08','2021-05-09','2021-06-09','2021-06-10']

df = pd.DataFrame({'username': username, 'page': page, 'date': date})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df_o2 = df.set_index('date').groupby('page')['username'].resample('M').nunique()
print(df_o2)
```

In the above mentioned example the result is:

```
page     date
sample1  2021-05-31    1
         2021-06-30    1
```

This is not good for me because users already liked this, so it would be:

page     date
sample1  2021-05-31    1
2021-06-30    0

Comment: Let me explain in  a different way:

Answer (score 2):

We can check for the non-duplicated values per `page` and `username`, then group the dataframe by `page` and `resample` each group on monthly frequency and aggregate the non-duplicated values using `sum`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['mask'] = ~df.duplicated(['page', 'username'])

df.groupby('page').resample('M', on='date')['mask'].sum()
```

---

```
page     date      
sample1  2021-05-31    2
         2021-06-30    0
         2021-07-31    1
sample2  2021-05-31    1
         2021-06-30    1
         2021-07-31    1
```